Cloudinary video doesn't load when I navigate to my website from Instagram description Link
I have a video issue in my Next.js project. Specifically, when I navigate to my website from Instagram page, the Cloudinary video fails to load. I've noticed that this problem occurs only on iOS devices. It seems to happen only during the initial render of the home page. However, when I navigate to another page and return to the home page, everything works as expected.
 const url = getCldVideoUrl(
    {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      src: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/CLOUD_NAME/VIDEO_SRC.mp4',
      quality: 'auto',
    },
    {
      cloud: {
        cloudName: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
        apiKey: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API,
        apiSecret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
      },
    },
  );

return   <video
        src={url}
        autoPlay
        loop
        muted
        playsInline
        controls={false}
        className="absolute inset-0 size-full object-cover"
      >
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>

Can someone please explain what the potential problems might be? Is it related to CORS or something else?

(1) What happens if you replace autoPlay and playsInline with the following... autoplay and playsinline (no uppercase letters). Is it fixed now? (2) What happens if you use normal HTML/JS to play the video src? Just in case the return part of your code is an akward thing for iOS. It should be able to load a regular HTML page with pre-defined <video> tag.

First of all, my editor is complaining about the use of lowercase letters. For example, it says, "Unknown property 'autoplay' found; use 'autoPlay' instead."
Regarding to second question, I realize that I didn't provide a complete return statement. This is a React component, and the video tag is wrapped in a <section> tag, as it is used as a hero video.

Are you able to provide a link to a CodeSandbox environment (or similar) so we can see this in action?
